# facebook opening on a browser not on facebook App

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm trying to make facebook for "someone" else opens on application, not on a browser, for example National Geography https://www.facebook.com/natgeo

Here is the code I have:

```
ddc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

      Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/natgeo"));
      startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
});
```

I found one on stackoverflow and I tried it and it has errors, here is the code:

```
try {
    //try to open page in facebook native app.
    String uri = "fb://page/" + natgeo;    //Custom URL
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);   
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
    //facebook native app isn't available, use browser.
    String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/natgeo" + natgeo;  //Normal URL  
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriMobile));    
    startActivity(i); 
}
```

the thing is I want, if someone didn't have facebook App, it will open in the browser.

---

Edited

```
package fa;

import com.f.fa.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button ddc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        ddc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ddc);

        try {
              //try to open page in facebook native app.
              String uri = "fb://page/" + natgeo;    //Custom URL
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
              startActivity(intent);   
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
              //facebook native app isn't available, use browser.
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/natgeo" + natgeo;  //Normal URL  
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));    
              startActivity(i); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: "natgeo" there is an error thought it should go there (I don't know) .. "uriMobile" is wrong and I don't know that they want the number

Comment: Please explain more clearly... if you get an exception, so show us. If you think the variables have wrong content, debug it. Try the suggestions in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a variable, which is not declared before (read compiler errors)..

Add `String natgeo = "my content";` before your try-catch block to make your code compiling.

Comment: That's nice. Please read ["How to ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting your next question. Especially include all relevant code parts. Then you shall get a faster answer ;-)

Comment: One question if you don't mind .. this code: [String natgeo = "natgeo"; String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;] it opens facebook application but opens at my account, and I don't want that, how can I change it to open natgeo account?

Comment: I don't know, you should open a new question for this